# Stripe payment and bank account

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible with Stripe to perform a test transaction to ensure that an account is funded?

I would like to :

- take the Credit Card ID at the moment of the booking (but no payment at that moment)
- make the customer pay AFTER the service has been done

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want is to place a hold on the card for the given amount, and then capture the funds later after the service has completed. When placing a hold the given amount is authorized and guaranteed by the cardholder's bank. You'll often see these types of transactions show up on your online bank statement when renting a car or when checking-in to a hotel room. When processing your payment with Stripe you would set the `capture_method` on the PaymentIntent to `manual` which tells Stripe to only authorize the given amount. Then, once the service is rendered you would [capture the funds](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture#capture_payment_intent). The following guide covers the approach in detail:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later